# Weird class name when using withStyles on react component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm upgrading Material UI to v4.9.5 and are running into a weird issue. 
My class names looks really weird which makes me think that something is wrong :)

The class names for elements in this component looks like this:

```
<div class=".LoadNamespace\(WithWidth\(TopBar\)\)-flex-2">
```

On my component I am using withStyles like this:

```
export default withRouter(
    connect(mapStateToProps)(
        withTheme(
            withStyles(styles)(TopBar)
        )
    )
);
```

I am using `{ createGenerateClassName, StylesProvider }` to generate class names like this:

```
const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName();
<StylesProvider generateClassName={generateClassName}>
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ThemeWrapper>
          <Root />
        </ThemeWrapper>
    </Provider>
</StylesProvider>
```

In ThemeWrapper basically just:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme} >
    {this.props.children}
</ThemeProvider>
```

Is something wrong, or are the class names supposed to look like this?

Comment: Any related code of how you are using `createGenerateClassName`?

Comment: maybe do these HOC's over a few lines, might help you get some clarity

Comment: @keikai I have updated the issue with some more code concerning createGenerateClassName

Comment: I think I found the issue. I was using some HOCs as decerators like this:
@withWidth({ initialWidth: 800 })
@withNamespaces()
Removing them resolved my issue